# Finding subfolders within parent folder

Tags: google-apps-script, directory, google-drive-api, parent-child

I may be missing something obvious, but I am unable to iterate through the subfolders contained in a parent folder.  My intention will be to get the ID of one of the subfolders.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Create Ticket");
  var FileID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var ThisFileParentFolders = DriveApp.getFileById(FileID).getParents();
  //loop through subfolders to find the admin folder
  var PF = ThisFileParentFolders.next().getName();
  var subfolders = ThisFileParentFolders.next().getFolders();
Logger.log("PF=" + PF);
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
      var sfldr = subfolders.next()
      Logger.log(sfldr.getName())
      findSubFolder(sfldr)
    if (sfldr=="TempUploads") {
      var TUploadFolder = subfolders.next().getID();
    }
  }
  Logger.log("TUploadFolder=" + TUploadFolder)

function findSubFolder(sfldr) {
  sfldr = sfldr.getId();
  var childFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(sfldr).getFolders();
  while(childFolder.hasNext()) {
    var child = childFolder.next();
    Logger.log(child.getName());
    getSubFolders(child);
  }
  return;
}
```

During debugging, the code breaks at

```
var subfolders = ThisFileParentFolders.next().getFolders();
```

with the error

> Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end.

PF shows the correct parent folder in the debugger, but this folder definitely has subfolders within it.  I have not yet tested the `findSubFolder` function, but I can't even get that far.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"var ThisFileParentFolders" will be a "FolderIterator" object.

A "FolderIterator" is a kind of array you can mainly acces via 2 methods:
.hasNext() and .next()

ALWAYS when you use the .next() method, you get the next entry from this "array" of folders.

So, instead of using the code line

```
var subfolders = ThisFileParentFolders.next().getFolders();
```

you should use

```
var subfolders = PF.getFolders();
```

Do you see it?
You call the .next() method for the first time when you save the return into the PF variable. This is in your case THE ONLY parent folder your file has.

Then you try to get the folders from this PF folder, but instead of using PF.getFolders(), you use one more time the method .next() on the ThisFileParentFolders "array" of folders, which has no more elements.

So, your script has to stop.

Hope, this helps.

I have to add something:

PF is not a folder!
It's a STRING!
So, you have to change the line

```
var PF = ThisFileParentFolders.next().getName();
```

to

```
var PF = ThisFileParentFolders.next();
```

to get subfolders from PF.getFolders()

Hope, this helps

Comment: Please use backticks to delimit code, or indent code with four spaces so it is highlighted.  Thanks!

Comment: Many thanks for that Richard.  I was too busy tying myself in knots there to think through the problem properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative solution, rather than a recursive solution. It is a slightly more generic way of finding folders at any level in one's Gdrive folder hierarchy, based on any given folder related condition.

###### Solution

```
/*Iteratively searches folders, given the amount of folders you would
  want as limit, based on the given condition, which is a function that takes 
  in a folder and outputs a boolean */
function getFolders(rootFolder, condition, limit = 1) {
  var stack = [rootFolder];
  var result = [];
  while ((stack.length !== 0) && (result.length < limit)) {
    var folderIterator = stack.pop().getFolders();
    while (folderIterator.hasNext()) {
      var folder = folderIterator.next();
      stack.push(folder);
      if (condition(folder)) {
        result.push(folder);
      }
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}
```

###### Usage

```
function isCalledPhotos(folder) {
  return folder.getName() === "Photos";
}

var personalFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("XCadfgg")

// Default parameter will be used
getFolders(DriveApp.getRootFolder(), isCalledPhotos); 

getFolders(personalFolder, isCalledPhotos, 2);

// If you want to search every folder, under the root folder.
getFolders(DriveApp.getRootFolder(), isCalledPhotos, Infinity);
```

**Note**: I understand this has been already answered. I am adding this for anyone who might find this relevant answer useful in the future.